# Build package for debian stable on old-stable

Tags: debian, compiling

I'm running Debian Buster where I build some packages with the devscripts package. I want to build these packages for the current stable Debian release (bullseye) without upgrading my system. I'm not sure where to start. Update my build packages? Set some flag in the build scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pbuilder` for this; install it, then run

```
sudo pbuilder create --basetgz /var/cache/pbuilder/bullseye.tgz --distribution bullseye
```

to initialise the Debian 11 build tarball. Then use `pdebuild` to build your package:

```
pdebuild -- --basetgz /var/cache/pbuilder/bullseye.tgz
```

See [the `pbuilder` tricks page on the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/PbuilderTricks#How_to_build_for_different_distributions) for a more general solution; you’ll have to adjust it to match the current stable and oldstable.